# Enable nbextension on IBM Data Science Experience

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sudo, data-science-experience

I have to enable File Upload widgets on Jupyter on IBM Data Science Experience. It requires the following set of commands:

```
pip install fileupload
jupyter nbextension install --py fileupload
jupyter nbextension enable --py fileupload
```

It looks we need to have `sudo` permission on the platform to execute the 2nd and 3rd commands which IBM Data Science Experience is not allowing me to do.

How can I do this on the platform to install the file upload widget?

Answer (score 2):

Users cannot enable notebook extensions on DSX Jupyter notebooks. The configuration of the notebook server, including the set of enabled notebook extensions, is under exclusive control of the platform operator.