# IPython Notebook: Why do not appearing the widgets after installing correctly ipywidgets in DSX?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science-experience

After installing ipywidgets in a Jupiter notebook, DSX (IBM Datascience Experience framework), it doesn't show the widget, just a static stuff or `A Jupyter Widget`

Example:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

widgets.Dropdown(
    options = { 'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3 },
    value = 2,
    description = 'Number:',
)
```

Result: A Jupiter Widget

I have tried several versions of `!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix` based on http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html, but I still got the same error message:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/src/conda3_runtime/4.1.1/etc/jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json'

Or installing with conda:

> CondaIOError: IO error: Missing write permissions in: /usr/local/src/conda3_runtime/4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users cannot install notebook extensions, such as the widgetsnbextension needed by ipywidgets, on DSX. IBM controls the configuration of the notebook server, including the list of enabled notebook extensions. At the moment, widgetsnbextension is not enabled. Therefore, you cannot make use of ipywidgets in DSX.

Your problem is similar to [Enable nbextension on IBM Data Science Expeirence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45182397/5629418).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --user
```

see also: 
[crashes on a permission](https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel/issues/170)

Answer (score -1):

are there any plans to either ship ipywidgets out of the box, or some other alternative to enabling widgets?

Widgets is a pretty basic use case for Jupyter and not having it is quite limiting.

Comment: I have found a workaround for this: use bokeh models and widgets!
Example code:

`from bokeh.models import CheckboxGroup, RadioGroup, Toggle
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, output_notebook

from bokeh.resources import INLINE
output_notebook(resources=INLINE)

toggle = Toggle(label='Some on/off', button_type='success')
checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
radio = RadioGroup(labels=['2000', '2010', '2020'])


show(row(toggle, checkbox, radio))`

Comment: This is not an answer, but a question.