# How to use python interactive gadgets in Data Science Experience DSX?

Tags: python, data-science-experience

How can one use interactive gadgets in IBM Data Science Experience (DSX)?

In Jupyter notebook I can use the following to have an interactive gadget:

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import ipywidgets as widgets
# Very basic function
def f(x):
   return x
# Generate a slider to interact with
interact(f, x=10,);
```

I found the reason why ipywidgets does not work with DSX in another question (it seems IBM controls the configuration of the notebook server, including the list of enabled notebook extensions).

How can I have a similar interactive gadget using DSX? Is there a neat way that I can get the same result as the above code in DSX?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPython Notebook: Why do not appearing the widgets after installing correctly ipywidgets in DSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959687/ipython-notebook-why-do-not-appearing-the-widgets-after-installing-correctly-ip)

Comment: you may want to review PixieDust (https://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/watson-data-platform/pixiedust/, https://ibm-watson-data-lab.github.io/pixiedust/) which is included in DSX and comes with a number of interactive charts and can also be extended to add your own required visualizations