# Is it possible to install Jupyter Dashboard extension on IBM DSX?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-science, data-science-experience

Is there any way to enable Jupyter-dashboard extensions on IBM DSX service?

Righ below is the extension I'm trying to install:

http://jupyter-dashboards-layout.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

According to the documentation, the following commands should be executed on Jupyter to enable the extension:

```
pip install jupyter_dashboards
jupyter dashboards quick-setup --sys-prefix  
jupyter nbextension install --py jupyter_dashboards --sys-prefix
jupyter nbextension enable jupyter_dashboards --py --sys-prefix
```

I've installed the Jupyter extension through the notebook itself with pip install, as shown right below:

[image]

However, when I've tried the next command required for the install I receive the following error:

[image]

I've initially though that it could be an issue regarding jupyter path, and tried the same command on the different jupyter binaries that are found on the container, but I still couldn't figure out why the install seems to not be working so far.

- Is there any procedure in particular I should follow to install / enable extensions on IBM DSX?
- In case this extension can'tbe installed, do you guys indicate any alternative for Jupyter-Dashboards extension that can be used to improve the notebook presentation?

Thanks in advance!
Felipe Silveira

Comment: Yeah, have you checked out PixieDust? https://github.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/pixiedust

Comment: Really nice extension @A.J.Alger thank you very much for the help! that was exactly the type of thing I was looking for, for the record I've created a ticket to IBM cloud support and they have confirmed that Jupyter-dashboard extension can't be installed due to some permission issues... so thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to enable notebook extensions for Jupyter notebooks running with an Apache Spark backend in DSX on Cloud. You're not the first to encounter this problem, see for example [Enable nbextension on IBM Data Science Expeirence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45182397).

Comment: Thank you Roland, is also worth pointing out what @A. J. Alger mentioned on another comment, that we can use PixieDust extension to achieve some of the dashboard funcions required.