# cannot enable nbextensions in Jupyter Notebook with new Conda Environment on IBM DSX

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-science-experience

Trying to install this package:- 
https://github.com/lspvic/jupyter_tensorboard
Python 2.7
I cannot enable nbextensions in Jupyter Notebook with new Conda Environment
[image]

Here is the stacktrace

```
Enabling notebook extension jupyter_tensorboard/tree...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/bin/jupyter-nbextension", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 988, in start
    super(NBExtensionApp, self).start()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 256, in start
    self.subapp.start()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 898, in start
    self.toggle_nbextension(self.extra_args[0])
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 888, in toggle_nbextension
    logger=self.log)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 413, in enable_nbextension
    logger=logger)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 351, in _set_nbextension_state
    cm.update(section, {"load_extensions": {require: state}})
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/manager.py", line 87, in update
    self.set(section_name, data)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/manager.py", line 71, in set
    self.ensure_config_dir_exists()
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/manager.py", line 46, in ensure_config_dir_exists
    os.makedirs(self.config_dir, 0o755)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/DSX-Python27/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/ibm/dsx/config/nbconfig'
```

Looks like permission error, Can it be install/enabled with user flag.

Comment: You can't enable nbextension. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45182397/enable-nbextension-on-ibm-data-science-expeirence for that answer.

Comment: @A.J.Alger That answer was for the Spark as a Service backend. This question is about a different backend, the new environments feature.

Comment: For the time being, you cannot enable notebook extensions in the new environments. We're reviewing the security implications of letting users enable arbitrary notebook extensions. Unlike JavaScript in cell output, the notebook extensions are loaded and executed for untrusted notebooks.